# Nothing happens after an update command for sql in C#. Where is my mistake?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sql-update

I'm trying to make a function to password reset. I have a database with 3 columns: Username, Password, Email.
I want to update the password for a specific email address.
I used the following code:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=WIN2CNG9\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=OOPII_Project;Trusted_Connection=true";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET Password = @pass WHERE Email = @email";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", md5Kod);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email);

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Ok");
    connection.Close();
    this.Close();
}
```

But nothing happens in my database.
I tried also to make a simple insert command:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c')";
```

Here the same result, nothing happens.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Run SQL Server Profiler to debug the SQL that gets sent to the database.

Comment: Is an exception thrown when the code runs? If not, are you absolutely sure you are checking the results against the correct database? If an exception is thrown, what is the exception?

Comment: Yepp, the sqlmanager didn't updated itself. I closed it by mistake and after reopened the database everything was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", Email);
```

should change to this

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email);
```

You have two parameters, `@pass` and `@email`. While for the first one you pass a value, for the second you don't.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Now I changed, but still nothing :/

Comment: If you try this `int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`, what is the value of `rows`?

Comment: Ok. I found the problem. Everything is fine. The problem was the fact that sqlmanager didn't updated itself.